# Azure Monitor Alert Rule deactivating without rule passing

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have an Application Insights availability rule set up to monitor a Health end point of my application.  During scheduled down time the alert repeatedly activates and deactivates, even though no successful availability checks are logged.  I would expect it to activate after the down time starts, and deactivate after it's done, but I get repeated activation / deactivation notifications.

I have my Alert set to fire "Whenever the average failed locations is greater than or equal to 2 count".

I look at my Availability Check in the Azure portal and there are no successful checks during this period.

I have a similarly configured Availability Check for another application that works as intended, with almost the exact same configuration, so I'm stumped as to why this one is producing false deactivations.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm not clear about "During scheduled down time the alert repeatedly activates and deactivates, even though no successful availability checks are logged.xxx". Can you please clarify it?

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same, have you ever concluded what is the reason of this behaviour @topher-j?